# Timer-controlled watering of house plants when I'm away?

Tags: houseplants

What are some good timer-controlled ways for ensuring the watering of houseplants while I'm away, for say 3 weeks?

One simple move would be to buy a timer plug which I can set, for example, to come on once a day at a given time and go off 15 minutes later. These are inexpensive. But what kind of kit would I connect it to that contains and dispenses the water?

Simple suggestions preferred.

Comment: Buying recommendation are off-topic here: there are region specific, and every 6 months we may recommend new things (so we cannot give a definitive answer, as expected on reference sites like this). Not cheap: Gardena has various kits, some with pumps (so you just need a sufficient large storage of water without need to connect to main pipes and risk of leaks in the connecting pipes. Or any other and some pot irrigation kit (to connect it to your timer). As a garden center.

Comment: I don't read this question as asking for recommending a product, but asking how to best design a timer-controlled irrigation setup for houseplants.  Outlet timer switch controlling a pump, full on irrigation controller, some kind of app-enabled-do-hickey...